# ASWebAuthentication and SFAuthentication login problem after logout on iOS 11 and iOS 12, not able to invalidate session

Tags: swift, authentication, oauth-2.0, sfauthenticationsession, aswebauthenticationsession

I am using `ASWebAuthentication and SFAuthentication`to authenticate on a OAuth2 server with `grant_type : authorization_code`.

Everything work perfect except of:

1. user login successfully
2. Logout by `revoking access token and refresh token with status code :200`
3. Tested that the revocation works <------
4. User press `login again` and `opens ASWebAuthentication or SFAuthentication according the iOS` version and just `goes directly in the app` like the session is validating that the tokens are valid somehow.
5. On iOS 13 ASWebAuthentication provides `prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true` which solves the issue but for iOS 11/12 it looks like it is nothing I can do (except that the issue is probably on BackEnd)

When I am logging in I am passing the parameters `prompt:login` but still it doesn't help.

**Questions**

1. Is there something that I can do to invalidate the session on ASWebAuthentication and SFAuthentication on iOS 11/12 similar to iOS 13 `prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession`? (I haven't found something on the documentation. Apple doesn't allow anything)
2. Is this an issue that can be solved on frontend (iOS) or it is a backend issue?

Thank you

***Providing the code just for documentation***

```
 print("Auth-Login : Process: Authenticate user")
    let state = String().createState(length: 4)
    let codeVerifier = String().createCodeVerifier()
    let codeChallenge = codeVerifier.pkceEncode.base64UriEncode
    let parameters = ["state=\(state)", "code_challenge=\(codeChallenge)"]
    let url = createUrl(parameters: parameters)
    guard let authURL = url else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.delegate?.removeLoader()
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            print("Auth-Login : Process: Run ASWebAuthenticationSession")

            self.webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: authURL, callbackURLScheme: "no.bilkollektivet.app") { (callbackUrl, error) in
                print(callbackUrl)
                if let error = error {
                    completionHandler(nil, nil, error)
                } else {
                    let result = self.getCodeFromCallbackUrl(url: callbackUrl, state: state)
                    completionHandler(result.code, codeVerifier, result.error)
                }
            }
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                self.webAuthSession.presentationContextProvider = self
                self.webAuthSession.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true
            }

            self.webAuthSession.start()
        } else {
            print("Auth-Login : Process: Run SFAuthenticationSession")

            self.sfAuthSession = SFAuthenticationSession(url: authURL, callbackURLScheme: "no.bilkollektivet.app") { (callbackUrl, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    completionHandler(nil, nil, error)
                } else {
                    let result = self.getCodeFromCallbackUrl(url: callbackUrl, state: state)
                    completionHandler(result.code, codeVerifier, result.error)
                }
            }

            self.sfAuthSession.start()
        }
    }
```